# How do I pass a file with square brackets in its name to ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Consider this ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i old_video.mkv -vf subtitles=old_video.mkv -acodec copy new_video.mp4
```

It works nicely if old_video.mkv doesn't have square brackets in its name. However if there are square brackets in the ame (e.g [old_video].mkv
I get an error "error initializing filter subtitles with arg ''

I tried escaping with 1, 2 up to 5 \ and it still never works

Comment: Try putting a ` \ ` infront of each square bracket.

Comment: Did you try enclosing in ' or " ?

Comment: I'm running a script in which I pass each filename as "$my_file" and the quotes don't work. I've also tried escaping the brackets with sed, which works for `ls` but not for `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not terribly familiar with ffmpeg, but from your post I can presume that the '[]' characters are somehow significant.  Perhaps the most straightforward way to deal with this is simply remove the brackets by renaming the file (the brackets are not significant to 'mv'):

`mv '[old_video].mkv' old_video.mkv
ffmpeg -i old_video.mkv -vf subtitles=old_video.mkv -acodec copy new_video.mp4`

You could always put them back after the conversion...